# representing external function using variable inside a function

Tags: functions, matrix, performance-tuning, function-construction, variable-definitions

Suppose I have a matrix

```
mat[a_,b_,c_,w0_,y0_][omega_,ak_]:={
{I TMM[a,b,c][omega,ak]w0, -I TMP[a,b,c][omega,ak]},
{TMP[a,b,c]y0, I TMM[a,b,c]w0 y0}}
```

Now the problem is that I have two sets of definitions for the functions `TMM` and `TMP`, which I will use the letter `g` and `m` to distinguish:

```
gTMM[a_,b_,c_][omega_,ak_]:=a*b*c
gTMP[a_,b_,c_][omega_,ak_]:=a*b*c*omega*ak
mTMM[a_,b_,c_][omega_,ak_]:=a*b*c^2
mTMP[a_,b_,c_][omega_,ak_]:=a*b*c^2*omega*ak
```

The above are just examples. In the actual codes they are a lot more complicated. So far my approach is to define two matrices `gmat` and `mmat` to take into account the two sets of `TMM` and `TMP`. Both matrices have exactly the same structure, the only difference is that one uses `mTMM/mTMP` and the other one uses `gTMM/gTMP`. This works, but as I extend my codes, it is becoming more and more troublesome (especially when the size of the matrix is something like 10x10 but not 2x2). So I try to use a single `mat` to represent the two cases, and define another variable `type` and do some something like:

```
(* definitions of gTMM, gTMP, mTMM, mTMP which are not shown here *)

mat[type_:"M", a_,b_,c_,w0_,y0_][omega_,ak_]:=Module[{TMM,TMP},
If[type=="G", TMM=gTMM;TMP=gTMP, TMM=mTMM;TMP=mTMP];{
{I TMM[a,b,c][omega,ak]w0, -I TMP[a,b,c][omega,ak]},
{TMP[a,b,c]y0, I TMM[a,b,c]w0 y0}}
```

But it is not working. How to make it work so that I can switch between the two definitions of `TMM` and `TMP` inside one single `mat`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use "type" everywhere:

```
mat[type_, a_, b_, c_, w0_, y0_][omega_, ak_] := 
{{I TMM[type, a, b, c][omega, ak] w0, -I TMP[type, a, b, c][omega, ak]}, 
{TMP[type, a, b, c][w0,y0], I TMM[type, a, b, c] [w0,y0]}}
TMM[1, a_, b_, c_][omega_, ak_] := a b c
TMP[1, a_, b_, c_][omega_, ak_] := a b c omega ak
TMM[2, a_, b_, c_][omega_, ak_] := a b c^2
TMP[2, a_, b_, c_][omega_, ak_] := a b c^2 omega ak
```

Answer (score 2):

In the very last line of code you have `TMP[a,b,c]` while it should be `TMP[a, b, c][omega, ak]`; the same for `TMM[a, b, c]`. Then

```
mat["G", 1, 1, 2, 1, 1][1, 1]
```

> {{2 I, -2 I}, {2, 2 I}}

```
mat["M", 1, 1, 2, 1, 1][1, 1]
```

> {{4 I, -4 I}, {4, 4 I}}